# Filtering packets by OpCode in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, packet, packet-sniffers, opcode

So if I understand correctly, the OpCode is the first hexa component of the Payload.

Is there any way to filter the packet if OpCode is already known? As i'm currently manually reviewing all TCP payloads to find this.

I found the following when searching for a solution:

```
rpcap.opcode == 41
```

But got no results when applying this filter - maybe because of invalid syntax or  it being the wrong filter for this.

Comment: The opcode, if it exists, isn't necessarily the first byte of the payload. It depends on the protocol. What protocol are you thinking of? Does it have a dissector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in this case, the packets were encoded. Using WireShark to decode the packets revealed the OpCode's as expected.